# Service Request/Response Contract Guideline For Multiple Results

Tags: c#, web-services, soap, soa

I have a Customer service that allows consumers to retrieve Customers by the following criteria: CustomerId, DriversLicense, EmailAddress, PhoneNumber.  My question is how would one go about structure a request/response for this service? I would like the ability to request multiple of these criteria and return a proper response. Keep in mind the service will return null for customers not found given the specified criteria.

A few choices jump to mind, but I'm trying to figure what is really the proper way to design a consumable service:
1) Have an explicit contract for each use case:

```
// psuedo code for operations - proper request/response patterns apply normally
Customer  GetCustomerByCustomerId(string customerId);
Customer[] GetCustomersByCustomerIds(string[] customerId);
Customer GetCustomerByEmail(string emailAddress);
// .. etc. etc.
```

2) Have a single request that encapsulates all of it; however, phone number is not a unique identifier.

```
// psuedo code for operations
Customer[] GetCustomers(string customerId, string email, string phone, string dl);

Customer[] GetCustomers(string[] customerIds, string[] emails, string[] phoneNumbers, string[] dls);
```

I see explicit as being the more readable option, but it's nice to be able to submit all of that information to a service at once and it decides what to do with it.  The problem with #1 is that it's redundant, but I think it covers every use case.  The issue with #2 is that a client may be confused as to what customer belongs to which request.  Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One quick solution is to use the transfer object itself as search criterion. This is very similar to [query-by-example](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/core/3.5/javadoc/org/hibernate/criterion/Example.html).

For example, rewrite the methods as

```
Customer[] getCustomers(Customer customerFilter) {
    Query q; // = new query on customer table
    if(customerFilter.isSetCustomerID()) {
        // add where clause to the query: 
        //     Customer.CUSTOMER_ID = customerFilter.getCustomerID()
    }
    // for each field
}

Customer[] getCustomers(Customer[] customerFilters) {
    Query q; // = new query on customer table
    // add where clause to the query for each field: 
        //    Customer.CUSTOMER_ID IN 
        //       [customerFilter : customerFilters].getCustomerID()

}
```